# editing a cell in a JTable seems to alter the behavior of the table after a Tab button is pressed

Tags: java

I have a JTable and I intend to add a row each time the Tab button is pressed whilst the cell that corresponds to the last row and the last column has focus. The code on Netbeans is as follows

```
private void tblReplenishKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_TAB ){
        int rows = tblReplenish.getRowCount()-1;
        int columns = tblReplenish.getColumnCount()-1;
        if(tblReplenish.getSelectedRow()==rows && tblReplenish.getSelectedColumn()==columns){
            model.addRow(new Object[]{});
        }
        if(tblReplenish.getSelectedColumn()==0){
            String code = model.getValueAt(tblReplenish.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            model.setValueAt(supplier.get(code), tblReplenish.getSelectedRow(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that if the Tab button is pressed soon after editing whilst the cursor is still blinking inside the last cell at the bottom, no row is added but focus is given to the cell that corresponds to row 1 and column 1. Any help will be appreciated as I am new to java

Comment: What happens when you use another key for replenish? What happens when you call `tblReplenish.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing()` before the first if statement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply however tblReplenish.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing()  causes the button to altogether stop reacting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you added the KeyListener to the table, but focus in on the text field when you edit a cell so your listener code is not invoked. You should NOT be using a KeyListener

All Swing components use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to bind a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. So you need to replace the default Tab Action with a custom Action of your own.

You can also check out [Table Tabbing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) which provides a simple API that allows you to use the default Tab Action and add some custom code.